# Tensorflow "feed" confusion

Tags: tensorflow

I seem to be misunderstanding the way that "feeding" is supposed to work in tensorflow.  Here is a very simple example of the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype=tf.float32)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(X))
# prints 0.0 as expected
sess.run(X,feed_dict={X:1.0})
print(sess.run(X))
# prints 0.0 again, but expected to see 1.0
```

So, how do I feed a value to a tensor and get that value to "stick"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf

y = tf.Variable(0.0, name='y')
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print("Initial value : ", sess.run(y))
    print("Feeding values using dict :" ,sess.run(y, feed_dict={y:1.0}))
    print("Final value : ",sess.run(y))
    t = tf.assign(y,10)
    print("Assigned new value to the variable using assign method: ", t.eval())
    print("Final value : ", sess.run(y))
```

Output:

```
Initial value :  0.0
Feeding values using dict : 1.0
Final value :  0.0
Assigned new value to the variable using assign method:  10.0
Final value :  10.0
```

I hope it clarifies the concept

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!  So, if I want to assign different values to a tensor over the course of a run, would I just redefine t each time?  (I.e.                    
t = tf.assign(y,next_val) followed by sess.run(t)).  Is this an efficient way of feeding new values into a tensor?

Comment: No, for that case you should use placeholder. I just showed you that both can be used. It is up to you which suits you more.

Comment: Okay, so what I have started doing is this: First, I initialize a variable, `X`. Then I do `X_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape = ())`, `update_X = tf.assign(X,X_input)`. Then when I want to update `X`, I do `sess.run(update_X, feed_dict={X_input:new_value})`. This seems to work. Is this an okay way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `tf.placeholder` instead `tf.Value` if you want feed network by some external data:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(X))
# prints 0.0 as expected

Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1))
print(sess.run(Y,feed_dict={Y : [1.0]}))
# prints [1.0] 

print(sess.run(Y))
# ERROR. Needs feed_dict
```

Comment: I believe it is supposed to be possible to feed a variable as well as a placeholder.  I was actually having trouble using placeholders; getting an error message saying that the shape or dtype of the array I was feeding didn't match the placeholder (even though they did match).

Comment: @Nain offered way for assign variable. But I think using placeholder is better way.